# Cannot set property " " of undefined

Tags: javascript

So I have this piece of code here where I'm trying to set a forEach for but I'm getting "Cannot set property "pos" of undefined.

```
                Object.entries(pos).forEach(([phaseId, value]) => {
                    let phaseToChange = this.getPhaseIndex(phaseId);
                    let cleanedPos = [];

                    value.forEach((po, i) => {
                        let cleanedAmount = po.amount ? po.amount.replace(/,/g, '') : null;
                        let cleanPo = {
                            amount: cleanedAmount,
                            OrderNum: poOrderNum,
                            salesON: poSaleOrderNum,
                            quantity: po.quantity,
                        };
                        wipePos.push(cleanPo);
                    });

                    phases[phaseToChange].pos = wipePos;
                });
```

Comment: What is `phases`

Comment: There are [thousands of questions about this same error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+Cannot+set+property+%22+%22+of+undefined). Please identify what it is about the answers to those you don't understand.

Comment: You should provide working snipplets for your code.

Answer (score 1):

phases[phaseToEdit] is undefined.

That means that phases does not contain a entry corresponding to phaseToEdit.

You should provide snipplets for these cases.